# Splitting data from .csv file and plotting graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a question where I have a .csv file like this:

```
Name1
x1,y1
x2,y3
x3,y3
.
.
x100,y100

Name2
x1,z1
x2,z2
x3,z3
.
.
x100,z100

Name3
...
...
Name10
...
...
```

Is there any ways I can split this data in pandas so I can plot graph with it.

Label will be Name1,Name2...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your graph needs to look like but here is one way to load your csv file into a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas

# declarations
data = []
data_dict = {}

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        csv_line = f.readline()
        if not csv_line:
            break
        split_text = csv_line.replace('\n', '').split(',')
        if len(split_text) == 1 and split_text != ['']:
            header = split_text[0]
            data = []
            data_dict.update({header: data})
        elif len(split_text) == 2:
            data += split_text

df = pandas.DataFrame(data_dict)
```